# MySQL hacer un INSERT y DELETE IF EXISTS en una sola consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, subconsultas

Estoy creando una app en Android con una base de datos MySQL, con la app te puedes registrar, loguear y cada usuario puede insertar un "filtro" que utilizaré después (son datos que entro con un insert).

La idea original es que cada usuario tenga tan solo un 'filtro'. He pensado que podría modificar la consulta SQL para que borre la fila del usuario si existe, pero no sé cómo hacerlo.

He probado a añadir el IF pero no termino de entenderlo.

Os dejo la consulta original:

```
INSERT INTO filtros(`IDCiudad`, `IDUsuario`, `Religion`, `Extraescolares`, `Coche`, `Empleo`, `TipoEscuela`, `tiempoDisponible`) VALUES (1,2,'atea','tenis',true,false,'privada','Completo')
```

¿Cómo la puedo transformar para que borre una fila si el usuario ya está en la tabla?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No es posible en una sola consulta, sin embargo, si lo que deseas es no tener que checar que el usuario ya tenga un registro puedes borrar condicionalemnte y luego insertar...

```
DELETE FROM filtros WHERE `IDUsuario` = nn
INSERT INTO filtros(`IDCiudad`, `IDUsuario`, `Religion`, `Extraescolares`, `Coche`, `Empleo`, `TipoEscuela`, `tiempoDisponible`) VALUES (1,2,'atea','tenis',true,false,'privada','Completo')
```

Desde mi punto de vista y por seguridad, seria mas sencillo hacer una consulta rapida y dependiendo de que exista o no, hacer un UPDATE o un INSERT

Espero que esto resuelva tu problema.
Saludos.

Comment: Ha ido perfecto, muchas gracias.